# Using ajax post/get call to send current form data to a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

I am trying to keep track of the number of results per page as I navigate through pages by sending them to a function in Django.  From my understanding the best way to do this is to use an AJAX GET or POST call, but I can't seem to get it working.

I have a function called `myFunction` in my `views.py` file that I want to pass my number of results per page to so I can manage the pagination between pages.  Here is my code:

In my javascript file:

```
function navigate_pages() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'autotester/myFunction',
        type: 'GET',
        data: num_results,
        success: function(data){} // I think this is legal to say
    });
}
```

In my HTML:

```
{% if page.has_previous %}
    <a href="?page={{ page.previous_page_number }} onclick="navigate_pages()">prev</a>
{% endif %}

{{ page.number }} of {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}

{% if page.has_next %}
    <a href="?page={{ page.next_page_number }}" onclick="navigate_pages()">next</a>
{% endif %}
```

In `views.py`:

```
def myFunction(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        num_results = int(request.POST.get('num_results'))
        paginator = Paginator(tuple_table, num_results)
        print "\n\POST: " + str(request.POST) + "\n\n"
    else:
        num_results = int(request.GET.get('num_results'))
        paginator = Paginator(tuple_table, 10)
        print "\n\GET: " + str(request.GET) + "\n\n"
```

where `tuple_table` is a tuple representation of a dictionary that has my objects that I am paginating.  What makes me think it's not working is when I print the `request.GET` I don't see the `num_results` parameter that I thought I was passing in with my ajax call. Plus, I get an error for trying to use a `NoneType` (because there is no `num_results` parameter).  I feel like Django and jQuery/Ajax should make this process relatively simple, but my total lack of experience with JavaScript is making this extremely difficult for me.

If anyone could either point out where I am going wrong or has a link to a more elegant or correct solution that would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The error lies indeed within the javascript, you should pass a collection of key-value pairs instead of just a value.

Furthermore you do not want to put this on a hyperlink element, because the click on a hyperlink element `a` will trigger a page reload on the new url which in your case is `"?page={{ page.next_page_number }}"`

You might want to put it on a button element and pass the value in the ajax call:

```
{% if page.has_previous %}
    <button onclick="navigate_pages( {{ page.previous_page_number }})">prev</button>
{% endif %}

{{ page.number }} of {{ page.paginator.num_pages }}

{% if page.has_next %}
    <button  onclick="navigate_pages({{ page.next_page_number }})">next</button>
{% endif %}
```

The correct version should be:

```
function navigate_pages(page_number) {
    num_results=5;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/myFunction',
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
               "num_results":num_results,
               "page_num":page_number
              },
        success: function(data){} // I think this is legal to say
    });
}
```

[Working example code](https://github.com/arpheno/ReverseForeignKeyFilterExample/blob/master/templates/ajax/base.html)

Comment: Hmm, I changed the data field in the javascript to what you have it at but I am still getting `\GET: <QueryDict: {u'page': [u'2']}>` as my print out.  Any idea why it's not passing in?

Comment: There you go. You don't want to mix hyperlink elements and ajax.

Comment: Unfortunately it is still not processing the request.  I know it's going into the function because I added `alert(num_results)` inside the function and on the outside of the `$.ajax` call and the alert does pop-up.

Comment: What's the stacktrace? Did you modify your code to have buttons? With hyperlinks, both gets are going to get called, your ajax call and the hyperlink, however the ajax is going to lose the battle. Look at the code i posted on github, i just verified it works.

Comment: I did change the href links to buttons, but I can't figure out what else you did to get it to work.  The problem I am running into now is that it's not redirecting to the next page.  I finally have `\GET: <QueryDict: {u'num_results': [u'10'], u'page': [u'2']}>` as my output (i used 'page', not 'page_num') but the URL should go from _http://127.0.0.1:8000/autotester/filter_report_ to _http://127.0.0.1:8000/autotester/filter_report/?page=2_ but it just stays at _http://127.0.0.1:8000/autotester/filter_report/_

Comment: Which I think is because the button click doesn't actually redirect you like an href does.  I think I read some where earlier that I need to replace the DOM?